# regex pattern needed for extracting multiple parts of a specific string in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this in my PHP code:

```
$string = "(A)[B]C/D/E:F?G";
```

how can i extract `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `G` parts from the string with regex?

i want a function, for example `some_function_do_some_regex`,
that take my `$string` as parameter and extract the
seven wanted parts from it

```
$parts = some_function_do_some_regex($string);
print_r($parts);

// OUTPUT
/*
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => E
    [5] => F
    [6] => G
)
*/
```

**UPDATED:**
I had to mention an important thing, but I forgot, I'm sorry.
Keep in mind that the seven parts in string (A, B, C, D, E, F, G),
are for sample and their value can change,

for example consider this:

```
$string = "(aaa)[bbb]ccc/ddd/eee:fff?ggg";
```

the output will be something like this

```
/*
Array
(
    [0] => aaa
    [1] => bbb
    [2] => ccc
    [3] => ddd
    [4] => eee
    [5] => fff
    [6] => ggg
)
*/
```

and another important note:
in the parts 1 to 6, there is no symbol character, we have `a-z` and `0-9` values, but for the last part (the part after the question mark), we can have any character like `[` and `/` and anything else.

It means that the parts structure are very important.

**Here is a description of every part:**
**Part A**: everything between `(` and `)`
**Part B**: everything between `[` and `]`
**Part C**: everything before first `/` and after `]`
**Part D**: everything between first and second `/`
**Part E**: everything after second `/` and before `:`
**Part F**: everything after `:` and before `?`
**Part G**: everything after `?`

Comment: Just use `\w` as regex. I don't know PHP, so I can't tell how this is to be implemented. But `\w` matches a single word. And will give you all the words that you want.

Comment: Use group capturing in regex with the `preg_match` function. Please google for PHP regex group captures.

Comment: @RohitJain thank you Rohit for the suggestion. the problem is here that parts A-G are for sample and their value can change. I updated my problem and give a description of each part.

Comment: @Mojtaba.. Will your `everything` be only a sequence of `words`? Can there be any `non-alphabetic` character?

Comment: @RohitJain yes. everything is only a sequence of `a-z` and `0-9`. but for the part G, (everything after `?`), there can by any character, including `non-alphabetic` character likes `/` and `[` and `(` and etc. Thank you for your response :)

Comment: You can use this regex: - `/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|\?([^?]*)$/`

Comment: @RohitJain i tested the regex and it worked 99.99% correctly. except one situation: consider that we have `?` in our last part, something like this: `(a)[b]c/d/e:f?this-part?i-mean`. for this code the regex won't work correctly and it return `i-mean` instead of `this-part?i-mean`.

Comment: @Mojtaba.. Ah! You didn't say earlier that you can have `?` also. Anyways, you can use this regex now: - `/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|.*?\?(.*)$/`. Now the 2nd part matches the complete string till the first `?` and then captures the part after that.

Comment: @RohitJain the last regex you wrote, won't work at all, it returns the whole string. Did I made any mistake or misunderstood your comment? I just replaced the previous regex with the new one.

Comment: @Mojtaba.. Can't you get the first capture group from that regex? I think you can use `$matches[1]` instead of `$matches[0]`. Again, I am not sure whether it's the way to get a capture group or not. However, you can try it.

Comment: @RohitJain Thank You. I got it. It worked correctly now. I will post the complete answer soon. Regards. Mojtaba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for **`Rohit Jain`** help. I create this answer:

```
<?php

$string = "(a)[b]c/d/e:f?g:part?with(non-alphabetical)[characters]!";
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|\?([^?]*)$/', $string, $sixparts);
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|.*?\?(.*)$/', $string, $sevenpart);

$part_a = $sixparts[0][0];
$part_b = $sixparts[0][1];
$part_c = $sixparts[0][2];
$part_d = $sixparts[0][3];
$part_e = $sixparts[0][4];
$part_f = $sixparts[0][5];
$part_g = $sevenpart[2][0];

echo $part_a; // a
echo $part_b; // b
echo $part_c; // c
echo $part_d; // d
echo $part_e; // e
echo $part_f; // f
echo $part_g; // g:part?with(non-alphabetical)[characters]!
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Rohit, here's the PHP implementation of the pattern..

```
$string = "(A)[B]C/D/E:F?G";
preg_match_all('/\w/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: thank you for your code and thanks Rohit for suggestion. I updated my problem, so it's more clear now. the parts A-G are not static and their value can change, so your code doesn't work in all situations as I wrote another example in my problem.